# Create a stored procedure to Delete Records postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

I have created a function to delete multiple records.In our table contain id as type uuid. We get the input is like array of ids.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.deletetVersion(item_list uuid[])
  RETURNS TABLE(id uuid[]) 
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  COST 100
  VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
  ROWS 1000
  AS $BODY$
   BEGIN
       RETURN QUERY
         DELETE FROM version WHERE id = ANY(item_list);
  END; 
 $BODY$;
```

SELECT * from deletetVersion(Array['b6ad1912-e4f1-4419-831a-c70df89ffd63','877898f0-2f3f-4890-a658-898e35ffee3a'])

But I got an error like:

> ERROR:  function deletetversion(text[]) does not exist

Answer (score 0):

it is because the

```
Array['b6ad1912-e4f1-4419-831a-c70df89ffd63','877898f0-2f3f-4890-a658-898e35ffee3a']
```

is treated as text[]

try the following

```
Array['b6ad1912-e4f1-4419-831a-c70df89ffd63'::uuid,'877898f0-2f3f-4890-a658-898e35ffee3a'::uuid]
```

as a parameter to your function

for example

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_uuid(item_list uuid[])
  RETURNS TABLE(id uuid[]) 
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  COST 100
  VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
  ROWS 1000
  AS $BODY$
   BEGIN
       RETURN QUERY
         SELECT item_list;
  END; 
 $BODY$;
 
 
 
 SELECT * from test_uuid(Array['b6ad1912-e4f1-4419-831a-c70df89ffd63'::uuid])
```

In case of deletion

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_uuid(item_list uuid[])
  RETURNS VOID
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
  COST 100
  VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
  ROWS 1000
  AS $BODY$
  BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
     DELETE from tableName WHERE id = ANY(item_list);

  END; 
  $BODY$;
```

Comment: I tried it.but shows an error like  ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 2: WHERE id = ANY(item_list)

Comment: You are doing delete query and asking the function to return RETURNS TABLE(id uuid[])

Comment: after deleting how can i get the deleted ids or any information?

Comment: Please give a sample of delete query

Comment: you have info when you return a select statement for example

Comment: is your table called version? can you do a select to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249510/discussion-between-ibrahim-shamma-and-robins).

Answer (score 0):

Your function should return either `setof uuid` - i.e. a table of uuid-s - or `uuid[]`. I would prefer the first. You do not need PL/pgSQL, plain SQL is enough. So the function is:

```sql
create or replace function public.deletetVersion(item_list uuid[])
returns setof uuid language 'sql' as
$$
  delete from version where id = any(item_list) returning id;
$$;
```

The version returning an array is a bit more complex:

```sql
create or replace function public.deletetVersion(item_list uuid[])
returns uuid[] language 'sql' as
$$
with t(d_id) as
(
  delete from version where id = any(item_list) returning id
)
select array_agg(d_id) from t;
$$;
```

And - as @Ibrahimshamma says - you may need to cast the argument to `uuid[]`.